# If statements with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Here's a function I wrote for a class I'm taking:

```
def idf(myMatrix,N):
    idfList = []
    df = 0
    transposedMatrix = list(zip(*myMatrix))

    for row in transposedMatrix:
        for num in row:
            if num > 0:
                df = df +1
        if(df>0):
            df= math.log10(N/df)
            idfList.append(df)
        else:
            idfList.append(df)
        df = 0
    return np.matrix(idfList)

idfList = idf(rawFreqMatrix,N)
```

I needed to do some matrix operations so I imported numpy and then I got this weird error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
    File"blabbity/blah.py", line 65 in <module>
        idfList = idf(rawFreqMatrix,N)
    File "blabbity/blah.py", line 35, in idf
    if num > 0:
Value Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use     a.any or a.all()
```

I looked up a.any() and a.all() but they don't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Show us the whole error message, traceback and all.

Comment: The code is alright. You are getting the error because you are passing something weird while you are calling the idf() function!

Comment: added the whole error message and showed idf function call

Comment: @JonAmen: `myMatrix` definitely isn't just a regular Python list. When I said stop using `matrix`, I meant stop using it in general, including in the input to the function. Use `array`, and use `numpy.dot` or the array `dot` method for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Give us a sample input to this function.

Comment: I think if you print `num` in your for loop, you'll see the problem. (I'm not saying that because _I_ see the problem, that would just be mean.)

Comment: `print type(rawFreqMatrix)` and put that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `matrix`. Always stick with `array`. Among other frustrations, `matrix` doesn't play well with iteration; it always gives you a 2D matrix result. This means that `list(zip(*myMatrix))` does the following:

```
>>> list(zip(*numpy.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])))
[(matrix([[1, 2]]), matrix([[3, 4]]))]
```

and the loop that comes next gets messed up even worse:

```
for row in transposedMatrix:
    # row is a matrix, and 2D
    for num in row:
        # num is a matrix, and 2D
        # in fact, it's the entire row
        if num > 0:
            # Rather than comparing a number to 0, you're comparing a whole row.
            # That blows up when the if receives it.
```

Really, you shouldn't be doing stuff like `list(zip(*some_numpy_object))` or iterating over arrays at all, but we'll deal with one problem at a time.

Comment: Sorry my variable names are confusing. transposedMatrix is just a regular python list that contains other lists. I've been doing research and apparently the error comes from numpy but I still don't know how to fix this

Comment: @JonAmen: Stop using `matrix` anyway. There's a good chance your problem will go away, and if it doesn't, you'll still avoid a bunch of problems down the line.

Comment: nope didn't fix the problem. I need the `matrix` anyway to do matrix multiplication that's the whole reason I'm even using `numpy`

Comment: @JonAmen: Use `dot` for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `num` is not a scalar when used in `if num>0:`.  It's either an array or matrix. That kind of `if` command only works if `num` is a scalar.

I'll try to illustrate (suspecting that your input are of type `matrix`):

```
In [1]: row=np.matrix([1,2,3,4,5])
...
In [3]: row.shape
Out[3]: (1, 5)

In [4]: for num in row:
   ...:     print num, num.shape
   ...:     
[[1 2 3 4 5]] (1, 5)
...
In [6]: num>0
Out[6]: matrix([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [7]: if num>0:
   ...:     print 'yes'
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Where possible, operations on a `matrix` return a `matrix`, a 2d array.  Even if one dimension is 1.

Now if I convert `row` to array, and squeeze out the extra dimension, its shape is `(5,)`, and `num` is now a scalar, and the `if` works fine.

When I run into problems like this, I throw in a lot of `print row.shape` like commands, to make sure that the dimensions of various arrays are what I expect.